# force user to enter year in YYYY format

Tags: html, validation, input

I have this input

```
<form:input path="proposer.dobYear" id="proposer.dobYear"
    cssClass="input-text small dayfield only-digits validateFrontend" maxlength="4" />
```

I want the user to enter it in the format `YYYY`. With this I can still use the format `YY`. Is there any way I can force the user to enter the 4 character format?

Comment: ```maxlength``` attribute should be used along with ```minlength``` attribute in this case and they both should be ```4``` because you want the user to exactly type 4 digits.

Comment: OK thanks. Out of curiosity, is it possible to customise the message that you get when minlength is not reached?

Comment: Yes, you can customize the message. check the documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxlength` attribute should be used along with `minlength` attribute in this case and they both should be `4` because you want the user to exactly type 4 digits.